# Implementing the Cimmino method

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, numerics

What am I doing wrong? I am trying to implement the Cimmino method, an iterative method for the solution of linear algebraic systems. The final output should be a vector.

Here is a description of the iteration step for the method:

[image]

Given my starting values, the following should be the result of the first few iterations:

[image]

Here is my attempt at coding the iterative procedure:

```
(* SIRT - Simultaneous Iterative Reconstruction *)

SirtMat[a_?MatrixQ, b_?MatrixQ, x0_?MatrixQ, error_Real, steps_Interger] := 
  Block[{x, abs},
    x[0] = x0;
    Reap[
      Do[
        x[i]= 
          x[i-1]- 
            Sum[
              (1/m)*
              (((((Transpose[{a[[i]]}]*x[i-1]))-b[[i]])*
                 Transpose[{a[[i]]}])*(1/(Norm[a[[i]],2]^2))),
        {m, 1, 30}];
    abs = Norm[x[i] - x[i - 1]]/Norm[x[i]];
    If[abs < error, Sow @ x[i]; Break[]];
    If[i == steps, Sow @ x[steps]], {i, steps}]][[-1, -1, 1]]] 

aa= {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}};
pp = {{1}, {1}, {1}};
bb = {{1}, {3}, {4}, {6}};
args = {N @ aa, N @ bb, N @ pp, 0.05, 50};

SirtMat @@ args
```

Unfortunately, however, this returns unevaluated:

> `SirtMat[{{1., 0., 0.}, {1., 1., 0.}, {2., 1., 0.}, {1., 1., 1.}}, {{1.}, {3.}, {4.}, {6.}}, {{1.}, {1.}, {1.}}, 0.05, 50]`

I am pretty new to *Mathematica*. Sorry if I am making too many mistakes.

Comment: You have two typos that jump out to me: 1) in the definition of the `steps` arguments to `SirtMat`, you mis-spelled `Integer` (you have an "r" too many); 2) in `x [0]=x0`, there should be no space between the first `x` and the square bracket. Please try to format your code according to the guidelines shown [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), and explain what you are trying to accomplish with it in more detail. You can edit your question using the "edit" link under it.

Comment: This expression in particular seems suspect to me: `Transpose[{a[[i]]}]*x[i - 1] - b[[i]]`, for two reasons. On the one hand, you may end up trying to index as many parts of `b` as you have steps in your loop, but `b` doesn't have enough parts. On the other hand, and probably what is stopping your execution immediately at the first go through the loop ($i=1$), is the fact that `Transpose[{a[[1]]}]*x[0] == {{1}, {0}, {0}}`, and `b[[1]] == {1}`. The two entities have incompatible shapes, and the subtraction fails.

Comment: hey MarcoB!! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Try this: `With[{k = 3, a = {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, b = {1, 3, 4, 6}, x0 = {1, 1, 1}}, NestList[# - Total[(a.# - b) Map[#/#.# &, a]]/4 &, x0 // N, k]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an expanded version of JM's implementation of your method that he proposed in comments. As an aside, I found [this interesting write-up](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~benzi/Web_papers/cimmino.pdf) by Michele Benzi (Emory University) on Cimmino, his method and other accomplishments, and the Italian school of numerical analysis in the 1920s-30s; a very interesting read.

---

I first propose a version using the built-in `FixedPoint` function, which will only return the final result after convergence has been achieved.

`FixedPoint` is nice to use here because it also allows us to seamlessly include your error checking and stopping condition, and alternatively a maximum number of steps to take after which, if convergence has not yet been achieved, the iteration stops anyway, and returns the best approximation up to that point. This is a nice "safety" feature in case one mistakenly imposes an unreasonably low error requirement, or the iterations do not converge for the particular problem at hand.

Default values have been included for the error and maximum number of iterations parameters: if those parameters are left off in the function call, the defaults are used; alternatively, the explicit parameters are used.

```
Clear[SIRTmat]
SIRTmat[a_?MatrixQ, b_?VectorQ, x0_?VectorQ, error_Real:1*^-10, maxsteps_Integer:1000] :=
 FixedPoint[
   Function[{x}, x - Total[(a.x - b) Map[#/(#.#) &, a]]/Length[a]],
   N@x0,
   (*safety stop: if not converged after maxsteps, stop anyway*)
   maxsteps,
   (*convergence test: results are same when      *)
   (*percent difference is within specified error *)
   SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2]/Norm[#2] < error &)
 ]
```

For instance, here is a call without explicit error and max iterations:

```
SIRTmat[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 1, 1}]
(* Out: {1., 2., 3.} *)
```

If, however, a more lenient error threshold is specified explicitly:

```
SIRTmat[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 1, 1}, 0.01]
(* Out: {1.01499, 2.12847, 2.49565} *)
```

Requesting an error of exactly $0$ is of course unreasonable, since the iteration may never stop; however, this may be useful when one wants to use `maxiterations` to control the number of iterations. For instance, if we want to conduct only $1$ iteration, we can use:

```
SIRTmat[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 1, 1}, 0., 1]
(* Out: {1.475, 1.425, 1.25} *)
```

---

Finally, if you want to see ALL intermediate results, simply replace `FixedPointList` for `FixedPoint` in the function definition above. Here is an example of the corresponding output:

```
SIRTmatList[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, {1, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 1, 1}, 0., 3]

(* Out:
{
 {1., 1., 1.}, 
 {1.475, 1.425, 1.25}, 
 {1.48542, 1.57292, 1.40417}, 
 {1.43052, 1.66656, 1.53229}
}
*)
```

Comment: Nicely done; thanks for expanding further on my behalf! As it turns out, a further dot product simplifies the whole thing: `Function[{x}, x - (a.x - b).Map[#/(#.#) &, a]/Length[a]]`. It should also probably be mentioned that `NestWhile[]`/`NestWhileList[]` can be used here, but I've often found `FixedPoint[]` with an explicit `SameTest` setting to perform much better, for reasons still mysterious to me.

Comment: Thank you so much for both , Marco and J.M. 
Really help me. I appreciate, a lot, all your time and effort!!!